# Is there a way to find where autocomplete data on Chrome was initially entered?

Tags: google-chrome, search, autocomplete

Without getting too into it a word has popped up in a search box of a particular website and I am wanting to check if that is the search bar/site it was initially entered or if it's been entered elsewhere and is just randomly popping up in this search bar because Chrome is being weird?

Hope that makes sense - Any help would be so greatly appreciated

Comment: Search bars can be auto-filled by the web site itself using statistics on popular searches.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome stores the autofill data in an SQL Lite Database that has information on the field name and value. It may not give you the exact website address where the data was filled but will help you get the idea by looking at the date/field name etc.

To look at this data, download and run [SQLLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

1. Close Chrome completely.
2. Open Start->Run **(Finder->Go->Go to Folder on MAC)** and paste this address: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\ **(For Windows)** or ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default **(For MAC)**
3. There will be a file named: WebData - copy it to another location.
4. Open this file in SQLLite Browser
5. Switch to the Browse Data tab and select autofill from the Table dropdown list.

Now you can see the data from Auto Fill which can help you determine when and on which website field name it was entered.

[See the Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usunA.png)