# Exporting data from Chrome not signed in

Tags: windows, windows-7, google-chrome, backup, export

When using Chrome **without** being signed in how can I export the saved sites credentials/passwords along with the most visited sites that popup on address bar or as a default short cut in the homescreen and in a way that can be imported to another Chrome.

If one signs in, would the all the data saved so far when using with no account be merged with the account?

Comment: Yes -- copy the whole profile. https://www.qore.it/blog/move-google-chrome-profiles-to-a-new-computer

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: What's the registry key needed there?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: If one signs in, would the all the data saved so far when using with no account be merged with the account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your passwords as a CSV file even without signing in.

Do this :

- Run Chrome
- Click the three-dots menu icon and select **Settings**
- Click **Autofill and passwords**
- Click **Google Password Manager**
- Click **Settings** on the left
- Under Export passwords, click **Download file**
- Type your Windows password and click **OK**
- Select folder and file-name to store the data and click
  **Save**.

This will export a CSV file with the following data columns :
name, url, username, password and note.

**Auto-fill data** is stored in an SQL Lite Database, so you
need either to copy the file itself or use an SQL viewer
to export the SQL table.

See the post
[Is there a way to find where autocomplete data on Chrome was initially entered?](https://superuser.com/questions/1228989/is-there-a-way-to-find-where-autocomplete-data-on-chrome-was-initially-entered).

Comment: Yes that seems to work for passwords. But I don't see any option to save the auto fills

Comment: I added this info to my answer.

Comment: The csv can it be imported again? Also If one signs in, would the all the data saved so far when using with no account be merged with the account?

Comment: You can just try it, but it's only logical that duplicate imported entries are deleted.

Comment: If I sign in is there a way to merge the data from the signed in account with the signed account?

Comment: For merging the signed-in account with the unsigned, if this doesn't happen automatically, then you'll to export the passwords from one and import into the other.

Comment: But there is no possibility that if not merged automatically after signing out, the passwords etc of the original anonymous usages are lost right?

Comment: I have never tried it, but nothing is sure as regarding software. If worried, ensure you have an export of these passwords.

Comment: for the record I found https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/170130544/i-have-chrome-profile-data-from-a-non-signed-in-account-can-i-merge-it-with-my-signed-in-profile?hl=en

Comment: Interesting, so Chrome's solution to the problem is to create two profiles - signed-in and not. This means that your data is safe, but I would still advise to take backups, just in case.